# Use Heroku binary instead of gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, heroku, installation

I have installed ruby 2.2.2 through RVM, and have also installed Heroku. I installed Heroku by downloading the most recent release from Github, installing the needed gems, and then symlinking it into `/usr/bin/` so that it could be found when I needed to use the command. It worked initially, but after a while (this may have happened on restart), any heroku commands now have a ruby error.

The symlinked binary still works correctly if I explicitly specify a path.

Output:

```
user@BEN-PC-LINUX:~$ heroku login
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'heroku' (>= 0) among 96 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global', execute `gem env` for more information
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
        from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/heroku:22:in `<main>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
user@BEN-PC-LINUX:~$ /usr/bin/heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email:
```

The only place that the `heroku` command actually works as supposed to is in `/usr/local/heroku`, I'm guessing because `/usr/local/heroku/bin/` is searched before using the path. Even in `/usr/bin/`, the error occurs.

Comment: The Heroku [toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) has an install script, running `wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh` might be a better way to install it.

Comment: @Exupery I tried that, but I don't want to install the heroku package itself (which is what that does) because it installs the system ruby packages as dependencies, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: You can create a alias for heroku command put below code in .bash_profile file `alias heroku="/usr/bin/heroku"`

Comment: @AnantKolvankar that works for me, post it as an answe and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a alias for heroku command put below code in **.bash_profile** file

`alias heroku="/usr/bin/heroku"`

**.bash_profile** 
so that it's loaded each time you open a terminal.

note:- You will have to reload your current terminal to have it working simply use

```
$. .bash_profile
```